# No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date. terraform plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
terraform {
   required_providers {
      aws = {
          source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
    region     = "us-east-1"
    access_key = "<my-key->"
    secret_key = "<my-sec-key>"
}

resource "aws_instance" "terra-instance" {
    ami           = "ami-09e67e426f25ce0d7"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"

}
```

I am new to terraform and have encountered this issue. I am trying to create an instance in AWS cloud using terraform and when I issue "terraform plan" it says "No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date."

can some one help me on this?

adarshpatil@Adarshs-MacBook-Pro Project-1 % terraform apply
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Comment: Means that the instance already exist. What do you want to do?

Comment: You can run `terraform state list` to show the resources managed by your Terraform state, where you should be able to observe a `aws_isntance.terra-instance`

Comment: It doesn't show anything                                                                 adarshpatil@Adarshs-MacBook-Pro Project-1 % terraform state list
adarshpatil@Adarshs-MacBook-Pro Project-1 %

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
The solution is pretty easy: save all before you run any terraform command.

Comment: Cannot believe that worked. I am using VS Code for writing my terraform code. The init command did not show me downloading aws provider plugin so I knew something is wrong at that moment itself. Running plan and apply shows me `No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration` and `Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.` respectively. I even pushed my code to my github repository so thinking that the files are not saved did not make any sense but that worked. Thanks @Tamar

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to force replacement of a particular object even though there are no configuration changes that would require it, we recommend instead to use the -replace option with terraform apply. For example:

> terraform apply -replace="aws_instance.terra-instance[0]"

Creating a plan with the "replace" option is superior to using terraform taint because it will allow you to see the full effect of that change before you take any externally-visible action. When you use terraform taint to get a similar effect, you risk someone else on your team creating a new plan against your tainted object before you've had a chance to review the consequences of that change yourself.

The -replace=... option to terraform apply is only available from Terraform v1.0 onwards, so if you are using an earlier version you will need to use terraform taint to force object replacement, while considering the caveats described above.

»Usage

```
Usage: terraform taint [options] address
```

source :  https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/taint.html

Answer (score 0):

This means your infrastructure is already deployed and no changes are detected. Try to change the `instance_type` to something else and try again. You will see a plan with the necessary changes.

Comment: changing the instance_type (I changed it to t3.micro) did not help.                            
│       status code: 403, request id: f901858f-fc1c-41a6-8901-2a8309ff5bcf
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 13, in provider "aws":
│   13: provider "aws" {
│

Answer (score 0):

Check your aws credentials file contents and see if they match your access_key and secret key.

Answer (score 0):

For the Terraform tutorial, change the name of the instance to "app_server2"
run 'terraform init ' again
and terraform apply.
It's common when you try the tutorial serveral times that the lock file , retains the old name and thinks that the instance is already deployed.